# Mutual Authentication (aka two-way SSL) for webservices with PHP

Tags: java, php, ssl, mutual-authentication

I am having trouble working out how to use PHP to make SOAP calls while using Mutual Authentication.

I have my Private certificate installed and working on my local server and the end client has installed the public part, and have also given me the public certs for their system.  I understand that if I was using Java I would create a client keystore (using the keytool utility) and access that with Java (with commands like:  javax.net.ssl.trustStore, javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword etc.), but what about with PHP?

I've considered using a PHP-Java bridge but that seems long-winded and potentially troublesome in itself.

I am slightly confused as this largely takes place on the transport layer and there aren't [m]any examples around.